# Showing the correct application in android

Tags: android

I have an android application which using some thirdpaty libraries. Some of them have its own app_name string in their own strings.xml. I build those libraries into aar. It's fine in emulator the application name is correct. It's the app_name string in strings.xml in my application. But it's wrong when I run the app in my android phone. It's using app_name string in strings.xml of one of my library. Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: it should not be doing that can you have a look at your manifest and confirm that appname in manifest is set to the string in the project

Comment: It's correct in my application's manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system selects the strings of those resources that match the locale on your phone. If you are using in the application default locale, check that the phone language was English (Unated States). So you need to add localization to your application or remove unnecessary libraries ...

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But how can I set the locale in my application? (I'm using different locale in my phone from my emulator.)

Comment: In project in folder res you have folder values. Create another folder named values-en_rUS and create inside file strings.xml See http://www.wilsonmar.com/android_localization.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to change the value of `android:label` for application tag in AndroidManifest.xml? Like this (from app_name to another_app_name):

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/another_app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    .....

</application>
```

Comment: The android:label is point to the correct string in my application's AndroidManifest.xml. But android:label in my library is pointed to its own app string which should be correct. But it's not in run time.